# Selling to external market in Brass, is benefit salary or cash?

Tags: brass

When selling cotton to an external market the scale (if there's any left after turning the card) provides what the rules describe as "**an additional amount**" of between £1 to £4.

It's ambiguous whether that extra amount is:

1. An amount in **cash**, as a one-off payment from the bank.  The amounts seem negligible if this is the case.
2. An additional **income**.  The point of doing this action is to increase income, so the word *additional* suggests this is additional income.
3. If it is additional income, is it an increase income ***squares*** or income ***bands***?  The scale is marked in £ so that implies an increment of a salary band.

Various other rule summaries and versions seem to just echo the words of the original, so they're not much help.

We've played both #1 and #2 without much impact either way, but still very uncertain which way this is supposed to be.   For info, I've a first edition copy of the game, so this may be clearer in later editions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra amount is in **additional income, in *squares***. According to the [publisher's website](http://www.treefroggames.com/brass):

> if you sell to the Distant Market then the additional income shown on the Cotton Demand track is added to your income level, it is not taken as cash.

And further on, clarifying that you go up by squares, not bands:

> When you gain income you go up a number spaces equal to the income increase, e.g. if you gained £5 then you would go up five spaces. Note that this does not translate into an increase of £5 in actual income, as that depends on the income band you are in.

The bands are only used when reducing your income due to taking loans.

Comment: When you sell to the Distant Market you do this instead of using a port. So you get the income of the Distant Market instead of the income from the backside of the port.